# Does a sysprepped install modify the boot record of other drives?

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

If I install W7 with only that drive attached to computer A and sysprep the installation, when I plug the disk into computer B where I want to run it (and change it to first boot disk in bios) will it make Any changes on the other drive on the system?

I am asking because I would like to not make any changes to existing disk and installation on computer B, but cannot disable the drive to install there with new drive as single and only drive so if I install it there it changes the boot record on the "should not modify" disk.